# shell script file (.sh) - dynamic command

Tags: bash, ssh, shell-script, lftp

I'm trying to build a dynamic command to execute in an .sh file, however, when I do it, it seems that somehow it adds \r characters so command is not correctly executed.

Notice that I'm running this over windows, using bash.exe. A sample of code:

My command.cmd file:

```
bash --login -x command.sh Parameter1
```

My .sh file:

```
#!/bash
#export PATH=.
cmd="ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add /cygdrive/C/$1/id_rsa & lftp -u myUser, -e \"mirror --verbose / /cygdrive/C$1/Output; bye\" sftp://domain.com -p 22'"
eval "$cmd"
```

If I run the command statically, it works perfectly:

```
ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add /cygdrive/C/$1/id_rsa & lftp -u myUser, -e \"mirror --verbose / /cygdrive/C$1/Output; bye\" sftp://domain.com -p 22'
```

But if I run it as is on the .sh file, it outputs the following:

```
C:\MyFolder\bin>command.cmd

C:\MyFolder\bin>bash --login -x command.sh Parameter1
+ cmd='ssh-agent bash -c '\''ssh-add /cygdrive/C/Parameter1/id_rsa & lftp -
u myUser, -e "mirror --verbose / /cygdrive/C/Parameter1/Output; bye" sft
'://sftp.domain.com -p 22'\''
+ eval 'ssh-agent bash -c '\''ssh-add /cygdrive/C/Parameter1/id_rsa & lftp
-u myUser, -e "mirror --verbose / /cygdrive/C/Parameter1/Output; bye" sf
'p://sftp.domain.com -p 22'\''
++ ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add /cygdrive/C/Parameter1/id_rsa & lftp -u myUser, -e "mirror --verbose / /cygdrive/Parameter1/Output; bye" sftp://sft
'.domain.com -p 22
Identity added: /cygdrive/id_rsa (rsa w/o comment)
'] `/' [Bad port '22.]
```

My guess is since this is running on windows something is not well formed in the dynamic command variable so the command does not run well. If instead of eval I perform echo, the output is:

```
C:\MyFolder\bin>command.cmd

C:\MyFolder\bin>bash --login -i command.sh Parameter1
ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add /cygdrive/C/Parameter1/id_rsa & lftp -u myUser, -e "mirror --verbose / /cygdrive/C/Parameter1/Output; bye" sftp://sftp.domain.com -p 22'
```

Which seems perfect.

What am I not doing right here?

Thank you.

Comment: Try [trimming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422491/how-do-i-trim-lines-read-from-standard-input-on-bash) your input (remove leading/trailing whitespace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, found out that it was Windows adding invalid characters. With Notepad++, saving as Unix/Linux worked like a charm.